# Finding calls of a method X in method Y

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

Is there a way in Visual Studio (i'm using 2013 Pro) to find all calls to a particular method X from method Y or one of the methods that were called directly/indirectly by Y (recursive that is)?

I considered the following two approaches, but both won't work in my case:

1. Putting a breakpoint in X: This is not possible. The method is built-in.
2. Finding all references to X: This is possible but will take considerable amount of time. Method X has been used in huge number of places.

I'm open to using a (free) plug-in if that is what it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a german IDE so maybe i use the wrong terms, but i'll try it anyway. You can use the visual studios [Call Hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409859.aspx) function. Therefore right-click on the method `X` in `Y` and then click `display call hierarchy`.  In the window below you can then expand the branch to your method `Y` and you only see all occurences of `X` there.

[image]

Comment: quick one: What if Y is only indirectly calling X, i.e. there is no direct call to X in Y?

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Your solution did most of what I needed. With some manual cruising, I was able to find what I needed. Would be nice if this window had more scoping options.

Comment: @dotNET: i haven't noticed that you've already commented. I'm glad to hear that you've got it working.